# POSTing XML with Chinese characters to the Microsoft Translator API raises deserializing exception

Tags: xml, node.js, translation, chinese-locale, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to translate from Chinese (Simplified) to English using the Microsoft Translator API.

A couple of requirements

- I must use the HTTP method `POST`, and not `GET` with a query string because my queries exceed Microsoft's URI limit of 15,845 characters (note that this is possible even when I use less than the 10,000 characters limit in the case of Chinese characters. The reason is that the query string has to be URL encoded, which dramatically increases the length, but it is decoded by Microsoft before the character count is determined.
- [The only translate HTTP method that allows `POST`s is the `TranslateArrayMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx), e.g. the `TranslateMethod` only allows `GET`s. Unfortunately, the `TranslateArrayMethod` only accepts an XML document, so  I must work with XML.

The following is an example of an XML document that I am sending:

```
<TranslateArrayRequest>
    <AppId/>
    <From>es</From>
    <Options>
        <ContentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">text/plain</ContentType>
    </Options>
    <Texts>
        <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <![CDATA[Hola]]>
        </string>
    </Texts>
    <To>en</To>
</TranslateArrayRequest>
```

This works fine, the result is:

```
<ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<TranslateArrayResponse>
    <From>es</From>
    <OriginalTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:int>4</a:int>
</OriginalTextSentenceLengths>
<TranslatedText>Hello</TranslatedText>
<TranslatedTextSentenceLengths xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<a:int>5</a:int>
</TranslatedTextSentenceLengths>
</TranslateArrayResponse>
</ArrayOfTranslateArrayResponse>
```

However, if I then add any Chinese character, like so:

```
<TranslateArrayRequest>
    <AppId/>
    <From>zh-CHS</From>
    <Options>
        <ContentType xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.MT.Web.Service.V2">text/plain</ContentType>
    </Options>
    <Texts>
        <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <![CDATA[南]]>
        </string>
    </Texts>
    <To>en</To>
</TranslateArrayRequest>
```

I get a weird response:

```
<html>
    <body/>
    <h1>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</h1>
    <p>Message: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.MT.MDistributor.V2.TranslateArrayRequest. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: TranslateArrayRequest. Line 1, position 298.</p>
</html>
```

Note that I also tried not using CDATA escaping, but it doesn't help. Changing the `From` language has no effect either.

I'm working with Node.js (Javascript), although since this is a generic HTTP API I don't think that should matter.

Comment: How are you constructing the XML - are you using a library/API or doing string mangling? If the latter, does the encoding declared in the `<?xml ?>` declaration match the actual encoding you're used?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am doing string mangling. I am not adding any xml declaration because this resulted in an empty response from the API. I tried to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` to the top again, and it's returning an empty response with status code 400 and headers `{"content-length":"0","date":"Wed, 15 Jul 2015 08:41:54 GMT","connection":"close"}`. In fact, I'm using node.js and the response's `data` event is never fired, so the server is never sending any data - it closes the connection without any response other than a status code of 400.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever note that Microsoft also doesn't add this xml declaration tag in their XML input, please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I encountered exactly the same problem calling one of the Microsoft Translator POST APIs from Node.js. The API works fine - returns the translation as expected - as long as there are no non-ASCII characters, but then when I add a single accented 'é' character to the in appropriate `<string>` section of the POST body, it responds with an error:

```
    <html><body/><h1>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</h1>
<p>Message: There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.MT.MDistributor.V2.TranslateArrayRequest. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: TranslateArrayRequest. Line 1, position 782.</p>
</html>
```

I figured out that the problem is that the `Content-Length` header wants the length in bytes, but I had been sending the length in characters. Why does this happen? Well, the typical way to measure the length of the body for the Node http request is to call

```
var length = body.length
```

and get the "length" - i.e. number of characters - of the string. This works when all of the characters are ASCII. However, it turns out that in UTF-8 non-ASCII characters (including my accented 'é') can be more than one byte each. So when the body contains non-ASCII characters the byte length will no longer be equal to the character length, and the character length is incorrect. In this case, it caused the Microsoft server to stop reading the message prematurely, generating the error message.

Instead we need to measure the length in bytes with the call (in Node.js)

```
var length = Buffer.byteLength(body, 'utf8')
```

and send that length in `Content-Length` header, and the Microsoft Translator API works again.

Comment: Note that not all accented letters take up 2 bytes in UTF-8. Some, like ẘ, take up 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the problem is not the Chinese language, but that MS Translator doesn't like new line symbols. When I stumbled into this error message, I've changed following:

1. In every content of <string> node replaced new line characters with empty string. These characters have Unicode values: 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0x85, 0x2028, 0x2029
2. In every content of <string> node replaced XML reserved words with their alternative representation:

   &   →   &amp;

   <   →   &lt;

   >   →   &gt;

   '   →   &apos;

   "   →   &quot;
3. Rearranged the entire XML into single line

After that, all worked smoothly. Concerning your particular example, the symbol "南" was translated as "South". I didn't use CDATA escaping.